# How to debug "An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated" error

Tags: iis-7

I am seeing error in IIS Log, Is there any way to know more info about this? We have multiple .NET apps running on IIS.

An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: DefaultDomain

Process ID: 7284

Exception: System.AppDomainUnloadedException

Message: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.

StackTrace:

Comment: What do the windows logs say? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: No, I don't see anything except above. Stack trace is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919789

Get crash dumps first, and then use Debug Diag or WinDbg to analyze the dumps. You will see all necessary information from it if you are familiar with the tools.

Microsoft support guys can also help if you open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to start looking deeper. Perhaps with logging and perhaps running the application in isolation with probes.

- Is it a problem? If not stop perhaps?
- First check the windows logs and look for more information.
- Next check the IIS logs to see if anything is recorded there
- Next if you can duplicate the error, try and narrow down to the steps to the bare minimum.
- Does it occur on one machine, many machines, on euser many users etc etc...
- Try run the app in isolation.
- Attach a debugger to the IIS process and see if you can catch this exception alone. If you can then perhaps rebuild the code with symbols to give more information.

Try all these and see if you can find it.